# Removing points and lines from MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, plot, line, handle

I have a figure where the user can click into. The coordinates of the click will get stored in two vectors x and y. Than I plot the newly created point via `plot(x_new, y_new)` and further there's a context me nu being created for this point which has a label `delete point`.When clicking on it, I simply remove the corresponding values of the `x` and `y` vectors.

Now I need to somehow delete the plotted point. Currently I'm doing it this way: When deleting points, I simply clear the current axes `cla` and redraw all points at once. But somehow I feel this isn't the best method since I want to also display text and some connection lines between the points on user input and it could get pretty slow when all the stuff needs to be redrawn everytime...

So I'm wondering whats the best way to do it? 
Would it be good to simply store the returning plot-handles for each point and than delete those objects when deleting the point? Same for connection lines and texts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manipulate the underlying data of a line directly using the `XData` and `YData` properties.

To remove the point at index `idx`:

```
XData = get(h_line, 'XData');
YData = get(h_line, 'YData');
XData(idx) = [];
YData(idx) = [];
set(h_line, 'XData', XData, 'YData', YData);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option, using "refreshdata", but I don't like it, because it is much slower and creates ugly code.
So I vote +1 to @Nzbuu solution, but I add this if it interests someone